# What is the special meaning of id in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

As you know when we want to go details of an item it is achieved by

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id })
```

http://localhost:xxxx/Item/Details/1

What should we call this "1" parameter? It is not a querystring parameter but what is it? Does mvc interpret this parameter as a querystring parameter?

And another thing is, when I set the link as below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { itemIdNo=item.Id })
```

mvc creates this link as:

http://localhost:xxxx/Item/Details?itemIdNo=1

As you see, they are quite different. Does "id" parameter have special meaning in MVC?

What should we call this "1" parameter? It is not a querystring parameter but what is it?

Does mvc interpret this parameter as a querystring parameter?

Comment: Check route table

Comment: It's not special. It's all dependent on your routes you've set up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your RouteConfig.cs, it adjusted as `"id"`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

If you want to change it, you can change `{id}` parameter as `{itemIdNo}`. And also `id`parameter in *"defaults:"* line as `itemIdNo`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a url path parameter. The name id is used to match against a parameter on the controller action with the same name. You could use any name you, like you have in the second example. 
You can specify in route actions where the value id should come from, the body, url etc